# Check multiple host accessible

Tags: c#, ping

I want to check the accessibility of multiple host using Ping. Here is my code:

```
void Check_Client(){
    string[] hosts=new string[]{ "192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.2", .... ,"192.168.2.100"};
    foreach (strings ip in hosts){
        AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(Ping_Callback);
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"; //32bytes
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 5000; //12 seconds
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(2, true);
        pingSender.SendAsync(ip, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);
    }


void Ping_Callback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e){
    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Reply.Address.ToString() + " accessible");
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();

    }
    else if(e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.TtlExpired || e.Reply.Status==IPStatus.TimedOut){ 
         System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Reply.Address.ToString() + " not accessible");
    }
}
```

I want to printout the result like:

```
192.168.2.1  accessible
192.168.2.1  not accessible
192.168.2.2  accessible
....
```

The question is:

- In the fuction Ping_Callback, how to get the destination IP? e.Reply.Address can be the IP address between the source IP and destination IP. It is not the destination IP I wanted like 192.168.2.2. Or how can we pass this IP address to the Callback function as parameter?
- What is the proper way to detect if a host is unreachable?

Comment: According to the docs PingReply.Address contains the destination address - just what you want. May be I don't understand your problem?
About the proper way to check if a host is reachable - using ping is one the proper ways :)

Comment: PingReplay.Address contains the router and gateway's IP address if there are in the middle. Seems there are multiple callbacks for 1 ping.